# Lua: I get error when I try to run a script in Windows

Tags: lua

I'm trying to run a Lua script from Windows but I only get errors. I've put my script inside the same folder of the Lua shell but if I write the same line of my Lua book `% lua name.lua` I get `stdin:1: unexpected symbol near '%'`
If i remove the % i get `stdin:1: syntax error near 'prova'`. I've found another thread here on stackoverflow. I've tried what the answer said but it doesn't work.

Comment: In the Lua book, `%` means command prompt: it's `$` on Linux and `C:\>` on Windows.  Do not type the `%` symbol in the command line!  Where did you type `prova`?  Is it a word from the file `name.lua`?

Comment: So.... prova is the name of my file which means test :P     It's only a ```print ("hello world")```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two different problems here:

1. As was mentioned in the comments, `%` is meant to represent the prompt, so you shouldn't actually type it.
2. You're supposed to run `lua name.lua` from the command prompt, not from the Lua REPL.